# Trying to truncate decimal values in all the cells of dataframe, but not working

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The Dataframe consists of table, the format of which is shown in the [Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4khi4.png). I apologize for not being able to type the format here as while trying to type the format of the Dataframe, it was getting messed up due to long decimal values, so i thought to attach its snapshot.
Country names are the index of the data frame and the cell values consists of corresponding GDP value.  The intent is to calculate the average of all the rows for each country. When np.average was applied -

```
#name of Dataframe - GDP 
def function_average()
      GDP['Average'] = np.average(GDP.iloc[:,0:])
      return GDP

 function_average()
```

The new column got created reflecting all the values as [NaN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkUOQ.png). I assumed its probably due to the inappropriately formatted cell values. I tried truncating that using the following code -

```
GDP = np.round(GDP, decimals =2)
```

And yet, there was no change in values. The code ran successfully though and there was no error.
Please advise, how to proceed in this case, should i try to make change in the spreadsheet itself or attempt to format cell values in Dataframe?

I regret for any inconvenience caused for not being able to provide any other required information at this point. please let me know if any other detail is required.

Comment: It seems need `GDP['Average'] = np.average(GDP.iloc[:,0:], axis=1)`

Comment: Woww, it was that simple and  i dint realize it.. Thank you so much, it worked like charm.

Comment: I just realised it is more complicated, so solution was changed. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is need `axis=1` for count `mean` per rows and change function to [`numpy.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) or [`DataFrame.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html):

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(100)
GDP = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
GDP.loc[0, 'A'] = np.nan

GDP['Average1'] = np.average(GDP.iloc[:,0:], axis=1)

GDP['Average2'] = np.nanmean(GDP.iloc[:,0:], axis=1)

GDP['Average3'] = GDP.iloc[:,0:].mean(axis=1)
print (GDP)
     A  B  C  D  E  Average1  Average2  Average3
0  NaN  8  3  7  7       NaN      6.25      6.25
1  0.0  4  2  5  2       2.6      2.60      2.60
2  2.0  2  1  0  8       2.6      2.60      2.60
3  4.0  0  9  6  2       4.2      4.20      4.20
4  4.0  1  5  3  4       3.4      3.40      3.40
```

---

You get `NaN`, because at least one `NaN`:

```
print (np.average(GDP.iloc[:,0:]))
nan

GDP['Average'] = np.average(GDP.iloc[:,0:])
print (GDP)
     A  B  C  D  E  Average
0  NaN  8  3  7  7      NaN
1  0.0  4  2  5  2      NaN
2  2.0  2  1  0  8      NaN
3  4.0  0  9  6  2      NaN
4  4.0  1  5  3  4      NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, I was thinking about it as well since when i used dataframe.min function, i never used axis = 1 parameter. Now i understand why i was getting NaN since there was one entry where it was Nan. This was really helpful. Thanks once again.

Comment: @NakulSharma - Glad can help!